# Force Calendar App to stay on current day and switch dates when the day is over

Tags: applications, calendar, screen, tablet, automation

I'm using a calendar application at work to display the Conference Room status. It works just fine on the "today" view but it will not switch days. So if today is the 30th, tomorrow the tablet will still display the 30th. It won't switch to the 31st.

I did notice that the app switches days when the volume button is pushed.

So my end goal is to either schedule a volume up/down button push at 1am every day or a "today" screen tap.

Unless any of you know of any calendar app that will automatically keep up with the current date. I've downloaded and used those other conference room calendar display apps but my boss prefers the view of a calendar in day mode.

Calendar App:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar

Device is always on, never sleeps or locks. Screen is always on that app on "today".

The tablets we bought:
https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-asus-memo-pad-10-16gb-tablet-3
ASUS MeMO Pad 10" Tablet with a 1.6GHz Quad-Core Processor (ME102A-A1-GR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions!

After I posted this I started changing my search terms. Macro brought up my salvation.
Using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) I created one macro that hit the home button, another macro that killed the calendar app running in the background and another macro that started the calendar app. 
I set the calendar app to open to Day view by default.
Without rooting the devices I couldn't just kill the application and restart it.
Turning off the display also didn't do it.
Along with these 3 macros I added one to turn off the display M-F @ 7pm and one to turn it on M-F @ 6am. So for my needs the free MacroDroid (comes with 5 free macros) worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Triggering the volume is one way it updates you've observed. I'm sure there are more. For example, turning the display off and on should also do. And while to my knowledge no app can (physically) trigger any button, there are some that can switch the display on and off.

One of those is [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), which is only available as paid app (though a 7-day-trial can be downloaded at its homepage). As a long-time Tasker user, I feel it's worth every cent as it's the most flexible [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app there is for Android – but YMMV, so there are [several other candidates](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=178) you might wish to check. Relevant for your issue are time-based apps, such as *Timeriffic* or *Llama*.

Now for the idea: Schedule a task for midnight (or shortly thereafter), have the app turn off the display, wait 1..5 seconds, turn it on again. This should cause a "page refresh" – with the side-effect of your calendar display being updated. Experiment a little with the start time (set it e.g. to 0:05 to be sure it's the "next day" when it executes) and the "wait time" (e.g. start with 15s to see whether it works, and then reduce it slowly to figure how short you can keep it).

Answer (score 0):

I only have a couple of suggestions.

- Purchase [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=tasker) to automate a task that resets your screen/sound on a schedule. Disclaimer: I've never actually used that app, but I've heard good things about it.
- Email the developer of that calendar and ask for that feature (his email address is on Google Play). And also leave a review on Google Play asking for that feature.
- Look for Android Calendar Applications/Widgets that are compatible with Google TV. In other words, if you find an application that was explicitly tested to be compatible with Google TV (which is Android-based also), then it is more likely the developer took the time took to test his application on a screen that never locks and that is always turned on from day to day.